# CRM Workflow Does not show availability to update related entity record

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

Two custom entities "Detailings" and "Project Managements". The project management is the parental relationship to the detailing. I'm trying to create a workflow for when fields change in project management to update fields in detailings. However detailings is not an available related entity type in the process. What am I missing? See screen shots attached.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like your image was eaten by the site; you need [10 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to post images. Add it as a comment or edit the raw URL into your post and someone will edit it into an image for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing something. The OOB steps of a workflow don't permit to access to the related entities.

You need to install in your CRM a custom workflow activity, as this one:
http://crm2011distributewf.codeplex.com/

It will make you run a workflow for each related entity in order to update each single record.

The configuration requires a bit of technical knowledge, but in the bottom of the page there is also a link to download the instructions.